# child view of custom view getMeasureWidth return different value at different time

Tags: android, view

I have a custom view and it has several child views, fabMenu is one ImageView of them, I write the following codes in onMeasure() method

```
 @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    measureChild(fabMenu, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = fabMenu.getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = fabMenu.getMeasuredHeight();
    Log.d(TAG, "onMeasure: width " + fabMenu.getMeasuredWidth() + "  height " + fabMenu.getMeasuredHeight());
...
}
```

but every time the log show different values

Comment: log the passed `widthMeasureSpec` and `heightMeasureSpec` parameters and watch the logcat, they are most likely different each time `onMeasure` is called

Comment: yes, widthMeasureSpec and heightMeasureSpec parameters are changed, but how come ? I have no idea .

Comment: read carefully `MeasureSpec` docs to understand  how `onMeasure` params are encoded

Answer (score 0):

guys ~

I finally 'solved' the problem.

I put my custom view inside a RelativeLayout before, but now I put it into a FrameLayout (then put the FrameLayout  into the parent view -- RelativeLayout ).

Then everything works fine ~